# Преобразовать содержимое файла в список

Tags: python, python-3.x

Дан файл `text.txt` со следующим содержимым:

```
foo
bar
baz
```

Как написать скрипт, который создаст переменную `text`, в которой должен находиться двумерный список `[['f', 'o', 'o'], ['b', 'a', 'r'], ['b', 'a', 'z']]`?

Comment: А что не получается?

Comment: Собственно разложить файл на строки, а строки на буквы

Comment: Покажите ваши попытки, собственно

Comment: Отвечая на сам вопрос: надо считать из файла (тема: работа с файлами), в цикле из строки сделать список. Можно вложенным циклом (темы: работа со строками, работа со списками, циклы). Как написать однострочник не пишу тут, явно вам пока не до этой сложности (да и сам не то, чтобы легко, напишу в одну строку:-)).

Comment: Так то это в одну строчку делается при желании, не такая задача, чтобы тут что-то нужно было подсказывать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не понимаю в чем у тебя сложность, но вот что ты хочешь сделать.

```
text = []
with open('text.txt', 'r', encoding='UTF-8') as file:
    for line in file.readlines():
        text.append([x for x in line.strip()])
print(text)
```

Если угореть то можно сделать так:

```
text = [[j for j in i.strip()] for i in open('text.txt', 'r', encoding='UTF-8').readlines()]
print(text)
```

Comment: Человек не просил написать скрипт (что не приветствуется правилами), он спрашивал, как это сделать.

Comment: Спасибо, понял, как это можно осуществить